# Split and Explode redirect

Tags: php

I have a list of dates that are being pulled from another website. Is it possible that when the user clicks one of the dates it redirects to the specified address? Currently, it is redirecting to my website with the page address of the website I'm pulling data from like so. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/tax-professionals/prepare-and-lodge/due-dates/july-2018/` instead I need it to redirect to there website with that address.

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents("https://www.ato.gov.au/tax-professionals/prepare-and-lodge/due-dates/");

    $split = explode("</span><h1>", explode("</span></Div>", $page)[0])[1];
    echo $split
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inspecting your element, you can see that the links in `$split` are defined as follows:

```
<a href="/tax-professionals/prepare-and-lodge/due-dates/july-2018/">July 2018</a>
```

This means that php will automatically add your BASE_URI when clicking on that link.

and this will result in something like:

`localhost:8080/tax-professionals/prepare-and-lodge/due-dates/july-2018/`

What you could do is add THEIR bas URI to the links:

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents("https://www.ato.gov.au/tax-professionals/prepare-and-lodge/due-dates/");

$split = explode("</span><h1>", explode("</span></Div>", $page)[0])[1];

$split = str_replace("/tax-professionals/", "https://www.ato.gov.au/tax-professionals/", $split);
echo $split;
?>
```